# Sleep/Hibernate Confirm Screen from Sleep/Hibernate Button?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I've got a Lenovo T400 running Windows 7 and I've got this bad habit of expecting the bottom left button to be CTRL instead of FN. Is there a way I can force or remap the Fn+Sleep/Hibernate to bring of a small confirm screen before it waste unnecessary minutes of my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simply set your power button to either Sleep or Hibernate:](http://www.demogeek.com/2010/01/27/change-the-power-button-behavior-of-your-computer-with-this-simple-windows-7-tweak/)

[image]

You can then use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to script any combination to turn your computer into Sleep/Hibernate

[image]

To see how just have a look at [this article (and the comments!)](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/howto_create_custom_windows_shortcuts_autohotkey)

Answer (score 0):

I always do the same when switching laptops however, there is no way round this.

Typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is simply a key that gets passed to the Operating system (so can be remapped), Where as <kbd>Fn/Function</kbd> is something that is just on the laptop which provides certain features and the OS never even knows you press it, so it is impossible to remap.